# Which Macbook app to use with WU-1a adapter?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3300, macbook

Before I buy a WU-1a adapter for my Nikon D3300, I'd like to know which app to download for connecting the adapter to my Macbook...

Ideally, the photos would auto-download to my Mac while shooting...

I would use my iPhone, but the photos should end up on my Macbook anyway and I don't use currently sync photos across all iOS devices... although, that may end up being the solution (turning on sync for iOS devices).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It appears the **Nikon WU-1a wireless mobile adapter supports only smartphones and tablets** running Android or iOS.  Windows and MacOS are not supported.

> Specifications and Compatibility: OS: Smartphones, Tablets:  Android™ version 2.3 or later (smartphone), Android version 3.0 or later (tablet). iPhone® and iPad®: iOS version 6.0 or later.

Comment: Agree - no support for Apple PCs: https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/wireless/wu-1a-wireless-mobile-adapter.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to use third party software. [DSLR Dashboard](https://dslrdashboard.info/connection-screen-buttons/) claims to support WU-1a and OS X, although at a quick glance I don't see any details on which versions of OS X it supports.

Most other unofficial software uses gphoto, which [is reported to support WU-1a](https://nikonhacker.com/wiki/WU-1a#gphoto). gphoto itself is available through brew, but I'm not sure what GUI wrappers are available on OS X and expose the PTP/IP support.